# Regex: How to match a string that every pair of 'a' has a 'b' between them

Tags: regex

Is there a regex that can match strings that every pair of 'a' has a 'b' between them?
For example, "aba", "ababa" will be matched, but "aabaa" or "acaba" won't. In addition, as long as there is a 'b' between every pair of 'a's will be accepted. "asdbatba" will be matched since there is a 'b' between every pair of 'a's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
Option 1:

```
^(?:a[^ab]*b[^ab]*)+a$
```

[[Regex demo]](https://regex101.com/r/rB7lO1/1)

Option 2:

```
^(?:(?:a[^ab]*b[^ab]*)+a)+[^ab]*$
```

[[Regex demo]](https://regex101.com/r/cK4tD2/1)

Comment: I'm sorry, but the regex should match at least one b in between any pair of a's.  For example, "accbdsa" will be matched.

Comment: Try this `^(?:a[^ab]*b[^ab]*)+a$`

Comment: The third one is fantastic. Thank you so much for helping!